# how to use the two-way data binding ionic & angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

TOOLS I USE : I am working ionic and I use chrome and ubutu os.

I am trying to do a demo project for data binding please check my plunknr https://plnkr.co/edit/CFSgfWDH5UY0XaDjRoBK?p=preview

Here i am trying to bind the user entered data into the formPost object but in console.log i am getting undefined like(`{Username: undefined, Name: undefined, EmailID: undefined, Password: undefined}`) if some one find any error please let me know

Comment: Did you add the angularjs file.

Comment: s i did you may see in my plunker

Comment: @MohanGopi as i have modified your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qvlGAQcK6PntppwZKNn4), this should work, why your $scope value is not reflecting because, controller doesnt know that $scope values gets updated and to cal the $apply when you are using the ng-model

Comment: but my code works fine with the same method when i use for another form i dont know why it is not working my can i have some more clear explaination for why it is not binding

Comment: @MohanGopi try to add that form code to this pluknr then i can help u out

Comment: @Webruster now I tried your code i am getting below error

Comment: ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: emilid is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.submit (app.js:31)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:26457), <anonymous>:4:515)
    at ionic.bundle.js:62386
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29257)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:62385)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16583)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2948)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2937)
    at HTMLDocument.tapTouchEnd (ionic.bundle.js:3064)

Comment: @MohanGopi somewhere you doing wrong by copy paste, its working in pluknr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106999/discussion-between-webruster-and-mohan-gopi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **HTMl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane ng-controller="formValidation">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">User Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="John" ng-model="username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Suhr" ng-model="name">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" ng-model="emailid">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" ng-model="password">
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit(username,name,emailid,password)">
          sign up
        </button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('formValidation',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.submit=function(username,name,emilid,password){

    var formPost = {
      "Username":username,
      "Name":name,
      "EmailID":emilid,
      "Password":password
    };
    console.log(formPost);
    $http.post("http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/Signupsupervisor",formPost)
      .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      })
      .error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
  };
});
```

Working [Pluknr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qvlGAQcK6PntppwZKNn4?p=preview)

**EDIT**

In pure **Angular** , 
the way you showed in Question will be worked you can see this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L22b1tb0/) for reference .

But while coming to **ionic** this may not be working as Expected because 
The problem is specific with ion-content because of the way this directive is defined in the Ionic source code. It specifically creates it's own child scope.

```
.directive('ionContent', [
  '$parse',
  '$timeout',
  '$ionicScrollDelegate',
  '$controller',
  '$ionicBind',
function($parse, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, $controller, $ionicBind) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    require: '^?ionNavView',
    scope: true,
    template:
    '<div class="scroll-content">' +
      '<div class="scroll"></div>' +
    '</div>',
```

Because of this and the way inheritance works in JavaScript, you cannot use 2 way binding. Basically your $scope.submit is defined in you controller and is just created as a new primitive to the scope of ion-content. It is not copied by reference like an object would be.

Read [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) . It's critical in understanding how this all works and overcoming these issues.

Comment: the way your answer is correct i think your way of binding the data is constant and it work every time fine then the **Oron Ben-David** answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo in your "EmailID":$scope.emilid, it should be $scope.emailid

The issue was with the ng-controller, it should be defined as a child for `<ion-content>`  you can check the code below:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane >
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div ng-controller="formValidation">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">User Name</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="John" ng-model="username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Name</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Suhr" ng-model="name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" ng-model="emailid">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" ng-model="password">
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit()">
        sign up
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', []);

app.controller('formValidation', function($scope) {

  $scope.submit=function(){
    var formPost = {
      "Username":$scope.username,
      "Name":$scope.name,
      "EmailID":$scope.emailid,
      "Password":$scope.password
    };
    console.log(formPost);
    }

});
```

Comment: sry i am getting undefined value still in my object

Comment: hi, I've updated my solution, note - you dont need to send parameters to the submit function, you can use the 2-way-binding of angular, like in my solution.

Comment: this is how my plunkr is also look like in console.log(formPost) i am getting undefined value

Comment: you should remove the ng-controller from the <ion-pane> tag, and add a new <div ng-controller> under the <ion-content> tag. please update if now it is working for you

Comment: yes you are right i accept it but i need those header in my view if have header bar the the form goes behind the header bar in view if i dont use <ionic content>

Comment: below the the header bar i need the form so only i use <ionic content>

Comment: you should keep all of the dom that you created, its all fine, just take the ng-controller to sub <div> under the <ion-content>.

Comment: in my header there is a back button so i need my ng-controller both for header and ionic contant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107015/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-oron-ben-david).

Comment: ok. so in this case you should use $stateProvide, which you can configure .state('customState', {url:"/url", templateUrl: "template/url.html", controller: "yourController"})  so each state in your app will include controller, and by this design you dont need to write ng-controller in your dom.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to bind your data to the HTML template is below:

Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name">

.ts code:
name:any= "Tanzeel"
```

So `[()]` used for two way binding.